Extremal example for chordal completion
A chordal graph is a graph without induced cycles of length at least four. Given a graph $G$, a chordal completion of $G$ is a chordal graph on $V(G)$ containing $G$ as a subgraph. A minimum chordal completion is a chordal completion with the fewest number of edges. I am interested in the following: What is the largest possible gap, as a function of $|V(G)|$, between the number of edges of $G$ and that of a minimum chordal completion of $G$? And can these extremal graphs be characterized nicely? I know that the problem of finding a minimal chordal completion of a graph is NP-hard, which might be some indication that my second question does not have a nice answer.
Let $f$ be the function we are interested in. Clearly $f(n)\leq \binom{n}{2}$. At a high level, graphs that are too sparse might not have many cycles, so we might need few edges. For instance, forests are chordal. On the other end of the density spectrum, a graph which is close to being complete does not need many edges to be added.
The best I could come up with was an $\sqrt n\times \sqrt n$ grid. It is clear that each $2\times 2$ subgrid needs to have a chord added. This shows that $f(n) = \Omega(n)$, as there are $n$ such subgrids. In fact, I believe that a chord needs to be added to the outer cycle of each of the $k\times k$ subgrids, for $k\in \{2, \dots, \sqrt n\}$. In an $\sqrt n\times \sqrt n$ grid, there are are $\Theta(n^{1/5})$ such subgrids. I think this shows that $f(n)=\Omega(n^{1.5})$.
Assuming the above analysis is correct, can we do better than this square grid example?

In the complete bipartite graph $K_{n/2,n/2}$, the minimum number of chords necessary is $\binom{n/2}{2}$: enough to add an edge between every pair of vertices on one side of the bipartition.
To see that this is minimal, suppose that there is a pair of vertices $x_1, x_2$ on the same side of the bipartition for which we do not add the edge $x_1 x_2$. Then for every pair $y_1, y_2$ on the other side of the bipartition, the cycle $(x_1, y_1, x_2, y_2, x_1)$ needs a chord to be added, and if $x_1 x_2$ is not that chord, then it must be $y_1 y_2$. Since $y_1, y_2$ are arbitrary, we are forced to add an edge between every pair of vertices on the opposite side from $x_1$ and $x_2$.
This is enough to conclude that $f(n) = \Theta(n^2)$.

Ah of course, nice!
